# how to get a value out of an Array FIRESTORE

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a `firestore` collection of `posts` and inside there is a document with this `userId: sycLjvCgroPpI5Os8kjJUXhEjv52_9de5e9d7` and it has an array:

[image]

This is the function to update the name

```
updateName ({commit, state}, data) {
  let name = data.name
  fb.usersCollection.doc(state.currentUser.uid).update({
    name
  }).then(user => {
  // update all posts by user to reflect new name
  fb.postsCollection.where('userId', '==', state.currentUser.uid).get().then(docs => { 
    docs.forEach(doc => {
      fb.postsCollection.doc(doc.id).update({
        userName: name
      })
    })
  })
 }
}
```

So how can I use `userId` inside the `userData` array for `where`?

Comment: You can't do that the way this data is structured.  You'll need to restructure your data to support the kind of queries you want to perform.  Try making an object with the uid as the key.

Comment: ohh what a shit. Thank you

Comment: Instead of using an array, you could possibly use a [sub collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) instead.